# Visual Studio 2010 .net 3.5 and lower messed up on windows 7

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, .net-3.5, msbuild

In the course of some troubleshooting last week I uninstalled .net 3.5 thinking I could re-install, and did so (tried atleast), but now i can't seem to build anything targeted towards 3.5, I try to reinstall 3.5 but it keeps telling me i have to do it in windows features, so I've tried checking and un-checking that. Any help would be great.

**Edit:** I should probably add that I used revo uninstaller and completely blew away 3.5.
[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You did restart your computer after you uninstalled .net 3.5, right?  Otherwise you can't re-install it anyway.

Comment: Yes, I've probably restarted more times then I can count today.

Comment: I've tried restarting, re-enabling, re-installing VS2008, VS2010, sfc, nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up getting my machine re-imaged, as I think when I uninstalled .net 3.5 with revo uninstaller and completely blew away the reg and existing, I put my laptop in a very hard to repair state. I've given up and gone the re-image route, as according this article, this seems to be the best way to fix the registry.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2007/03/26/how-to-repair-the-net-framework-2-0-and-3-0-on-windows-vista.aspx

Answer (score 3):

You have broken the .NET Framework. Congrats been there this is no fun. If you have Googled you surely have found

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2007/03/26/how-to-repair-the-net-framework-2-0-and-3-0-on-windows-vista.aspx

There it is mentioned that the .Net Framework on Vista+ is part of the OS you you cannot reinstall it as usual. The mentioned trick to call

- sfc.exe /scannow

does not help since it does only repair missing files in locations under MSI and Trusted Installer control.

After searching a lot on my file system I did finally find my assemblies in an unexpected place. They are all installed a second time into C:\Windows\WinSxS... which is normally only used for unmanaged side by side dlls like the C-Runtimes or any other dll. I do not know how they did install it but normal MSI installations which do install into the GAC do not install the managed assemblies a second time into the WinSxS folder.

On a second thought it sounds reasonable since MSI and the installers do only care about files in the WinSxS system32 and other specially protected folders. The GAC is not protected in this way which means that the usual repair mechanisms do not work.

My way out of this mess was to use gacutil to simply install everything into the GAC again which is intallable from the WinSxS assemblies. With the following commands I had success:

```
 1. C:\Windows\winsxs>for /D %i in (*_System.*) do for %j in (%i\*.dll)
    do echo %~fj >> %TEMP%\assemblies.txt 
 2. C:\Windows\winsxs>for /D %i in (*_microsoft.*) do for %j in (%i\*.dll) do echo %~fj >> %TEMP%\assemblies.txt
 3. for /F %i in (%TEMP%\assemblies.txt) do gacutil /i %i
```

I have nowhere found any explanation why the .NET assemblies are installed a second time in the WinSxS folder. MSI does treat managed and unmanaged assemblies nearly the same way but with the normal installers I do not get this behaviour. I do know that MS uses for Windows Components a technology similar to MSI but the underlying engine is quite different.

When you get OS patches they look like regular msi files but they aren´t. If you try to repackage them you will find out that the installation does no longer work. It would be very interesting to get more infos on this dark subject.

Comment: well that dumps out a lot messages, but it still dosen't seem to fix it.

Comment: Visual Studio does not use references from the GAC but from Reference Assemblies folders. You need to fill this folder as well to make it work again. They are stored in registry keys: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306149/en-us I suspect you have missing files there.

Comment: it appears i don't have gacutil installed

Comment: and now i can install the .net 2.0 sdk to get gac util

Comment: Gacutil is installed together with VS2010. Look at Add/Remove Programs and right click "Microsoft Visual Studio 2010" and "Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7". There you can select change and follow the menu until you can repair your installation. That should bring gacutil and all the other tools back.